# Cannot parse json array as nsarray in swift 2

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I have the following json as a response :

```
[
{
    "id_post": "1",
    "id_type": "1",
    "title": "I hffjj",
    "body": "nothing at all",
    "visitors": "0",
    "extrabutton": "none",
    "deviceid": "468af7f24ade50c9"
},
{
    "id_post": "2",
    "id_type": "1",
    "title": "suxk my ",
    "body": "sssusushshd",
    "visitors": "0",
    "extrabutton": "none",
    "deviceid": "468af7f24ade50c9"
}
]
```

I am trying to parse it as an `NSArray` as the following :

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
            guard data != nil else {
                print("no data found: \(error)")
                return
            }

            do {
                if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSArray {
                    print("Success: \(jsonResult)")
                }
            } catch let parseError {
                print(parseError)
            }
        }
```

I always get the error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Minor point, but if you change your guard to `guard let data = data else { .... }` you can do away with the exclamation marks in the following code.

Answer (score 2):

I think you try this one and use allow `NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments` options which give you a proper json

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in guard data != nil else {
           print("no data found: \(error)")
            return
           }

        do {
            if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments | NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as? NSArray {
                print("Success: \(jsonResult)")
            }
        } catch let parseError {
            print(parseError)
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Another error: Binary operator cannot be applied to two NSJSONReadingOptions operands.

Comment: Try `options:[.AllowFragments, .MutableContainers]`. The syntax changed in Swift 2.

Comment: The options worked, the error is "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}" now.

Answer (score 1):

The data you get back is clearly not a UTF-8 string containing JSON.  We can see this because the string appears to be set to

```
Current character set: utf8
NULL
```

when the error message is printed out.

I'd start by issuing the URL request from an ordinary web browser to make sure that the response is what you expect.

Comment: The response is what I expect. My problem isn't the utf8 encoding but the "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."
utf8 is in the error handling branch

Comment: @xanyi Yesterday your question contained a second error message which printed out the content of the data which was clearly not a JSON string.  Why do you think this is not relevant?  It would cause exactly the problem you are seeing,

Answer (score -1):

For swift 3 and Xcode 8.1 you can use this:

```
 let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [.allowFragments, .mutableContainers])
```

Comment: The JSON in the question doesn't need any of those options and `.mutableContainers` is meaningless in Swift anyway.